# How to center Text vertically?

Tags: html, css, text-align

How to center the Text `Test Text` vertically? see [here](http://jsfiddle.net/wfkd6Lbn/5/)

I want to make distance between the text and the boarder bottom equals the distance between the text and the boarder top. 
 `

Comment: Could we see your code please?

Comment: Is it single lined text? If yes, than use line height same as height

Comment: yes its only one word

Comment: Maybe this will help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/396145/how-to-vertically-center-a-div-for-all-browsers

Comment: line-height is not going to help here, because element is made of different size borders, whole approach should be different.

Answer (score 4):

For single lined text, use `line-height` that is equal to `height` (or rounded up to even number).

```css
#a {
  display: inline-block;
  padding-right: 20px;
  padding-left: 15px;
  font-family: 'Roboto';
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-stretch: condensed;
  COLOR: white;
  border-left: 10px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 25px solid;
  border-bottom-color: #FF3300;
  height: 0;
  line-height: 26px;
  top: 50%;
}
```

```html
<span id="a">TEST TEXT</span>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `line-height: 25px`(will work for single-line text only).

```css
#a {
  display: inline-block;
  padding-right: 20px;
  padding-left: 15px;
  font-family: 'Roboto';
  font-size: 12px;
  line-height: 25px;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-stretch: condensed;
  COLOR: white;
  border-left: 10px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 25px solid;
  border-bottom-color: #FF3300;
  height: 0;
  top: 50%;
}
```

```html
<span id="a">TEST TEXT</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `:before` pseudo element for left part, line height is not going to work with `bottom-border`. I updated your fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/wfkd6Lbn/8/

Answer (score 0):

```css
.area { 
  width: 300px; 
  height: 300px;  
  position: relative;
}

.bubble { 
  position: absolute; 
  left: 93px; 
  top: 21px; 
  width: 135px; 
  height: 84px; 
  display: table; 
}

.bubble p {
  display: table-cell; 
  vertical-align: middle; 
  text-align: center;
```

```html
<div class="area">
      <div class="bubble">
          <p>To look best, text should really be centered inside this bubble both vertically and horizontally.</p>
      </div>
</div>
```